# Passing values between methods

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I've got method where I read value into variable

```
public void displayFromExcel(String xlsPath) {
. 
. 
. 
pole[i] = cell.getNumericCellValue();
.
.
pole1[j] = richTextString;
```

Then I have method where I build a `String` using `StringBuilder`

```
    private void getHenkValues (StringBuilder sb) { 
    sb.append("<ColumnValue name=\"hen_allockey\">" + pole1[j] + "</ColumnValue\">\r\n"
            +"<ColumnValue name=\"hen_percentage\">"+ pole[i] + "</ColumnValue\">\r\n");
}
```

Then I have method where I write it into file:

```
protected void jobRun() throws Exception {
sb = new StringBuilder();
getHenkValues(sb);
String epilog1 = sb.toString();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test\\osem.xml");
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
osw.write(epilog1);
osw.flush();
osw.close();  
}
```

And in method `main` I call the method `jobrun`.

How can I get the values from `pole[i]`, `pole1[j]` from method `displayFromExcel` to method `getHenkValues`?

Comment: SO is a Q/A site. Don't say sorry when you ask.

Comment: If I correctly understand your question you want to pass `pole[i]` and `pole1[j]` from `displayFromExcel` to `getHenkValues` ?

Comment: And since you're new: you can leave out most of the filler phrases "my question is...", "I have a problem:" and so on.

Comment: @Ummar: yes you are right. and if is possible I need detailed answer. I don't know a lot from java :)

Comment: thank you for changing name of my question...now I know what I am looking for...and it will be easyer to find answen on google

Answer (score 2):

Your `displayFromExcel` method need to return them (using a custom class or a collection of some sort, perhaps an array).

Your `getHenkValues` needs to accept these values as well, you could try something like:

```
getHenkValues(StringBuilder sb, Object value1, Object value2)
```

or whatever is relevant for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You could make pole and pole1 private fields of the class in which displayFromExcel, getHenkValues and jobRun are located:

```
private Object[] pole;
private String[] pole1;
```

Then you can assign values to these arrays in one method and access them in another.